# How can I set the first value as default in autocomplete text box when did not select any value in list - jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using autocomplete in my jsp page.

I want to set the first value in an autocomplete text box. When ever the user leaves the text box, the first value should be selected.

How can I do that?

HTML:

```
<input id="auto">
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Squirrell', 'Lizard'],
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

});

The jsfiddle link is given below.

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/vFWUt/

Comment: I would look into this: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#extension-points . This allows you to customize the widget to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this? I'm not 100% certain how to access your `source:` array otherwise, though there may be a way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Squirrell', 'Lizard'];
    $("#auto").autocomplete({
        source: ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Squirrell', 'Lizard'],
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
    $("#auto").blur(function(){
        if(this.value==""){
         this.value = arr[0];   
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: hai gtr, plz see redbus.net, it do different ,in autocomplete text box fill first listed value.how it done